# Take a column from a Dataframe and normalize all of the other columns against it?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I've got a Dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(np.arange(0,9), (3,3)))

print(df)
   0  1  2
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
```

I'd like to normalize two of the columns against a reference column. For example, if I chose `df[0]` as my reference column, then `df[1]` and `df[2]` would also have a mean of 3 and a standard deviation of 3.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Could you please post sample of expected output in your question and let us know then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift and scale the values in each column by the mean and standard deviation of the reference column `ref`:

```
ref = 0
means = df.mean()
stds = df.std()
(df - means + means[ref]) / stds * stds[ref]
```